# Switching columns and rows with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to make a series of rows based off of an array of objects.  i am trying to produce a series of columns displaying each property of the objects (each has the same properties), with rows showing the property values.

I am currently using the following code.

```
<div ng-controller="HomepageController" >

<!-- form holding the name -->
  <form td-ui-grid-row ng-controller="HomepageController" 
    ng-submit="vm.addData()" class="form-inline party-form" ng-repeat="dataEntry in vm.dataList">
    <div td-ui-grid-col="3xs" ng-repeat="dataContent in dataEntry">
      dataContent:{{dataContent}}
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

vm.data is the following series of data: [{"name":"davis","phone":"11111111111"},{"name":"graeham","phone":"222222222222"},{"name":"eric","phone":"33333333333"}]

and i want to produce the table of vales to look like:

davis              graeham          eric

11111111111        222222222222     33333333333

however,  I am getting the inverse:

davis     11111111111

graeham   222222222222

eric      33333333333

I simplified the code so that it is easier to look and work with:

```
<div ng-controller="HomepageController" >

<!-- form holding the name -->
  <form td-ui-grid-row ng-controller="HomepageController" ng-submit="vm.addData()" class="form-inline party-form">
    <table>

      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="person in vm.dataList">
          <input ng-model="vm.newData.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{person.name}}" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="person in vm.dataList">
          <input ng-model="vm.newData.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{person.phone}}" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </form>

</div>
```

This code is now showing the proper output format,  however i need to be able to cycle through any number of object attributes

```
.directive('tdUiGridRow', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.addClass('td-row');
        if (attrs.tdUiGridRow) {
          element.addClass('td-row-type-'+attrs.tdUiGridRow);
        }
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: I have come up with a new potential way to achieve the result you are looking for; however, I think that I need more information, since it appears that you are using some sort of grid directive and I want to make it work with this.  what grid directive are you using?

Comment: I think you are referring to "td-ui-grid-row", correct? or are you talking about the "Homepage Controller?

Comment: The td-ui-grid-row type lines, yes

Comment: ok, i added in the td-ui-grid-row directive to my post above.

also,  thank you for all of your help so far!  it means a lot to a novice like me  :)

Comment: So the directive is just adding CSS? If that is the case, I will just edit my answer with the alternative using table elements like the existing one, and hopefully you can see how to modify it for your css

Comment: yes,  that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Please do below. You would create two loops, one for name and one for phone.

```
<div><span ng-repeat="contact  in vm.data">{{contact.name}}</span></div>
<div><span ng-repeat="contact in vm.data">{{contact.phone}}</span></div>
```

Comment: I tried this,  but i seem to be running into the same issue of the name and phone being in the same row, instead of all of the names being in a row

Comment: . You would create two ng-repeat loops

Comment: I just added simplified and updated code to my post,  however,  i am still running into the same issue.  i cannot seem to post in the same row

Answer (score 1):

This simply requires looping through the data multiple times, and extracting one property each time.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="person in data">{{person.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="person in data">{{person.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tXmaTmPuwbsN62cQLJuF?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much!  however,  the number of rows will be variable (may be 3 attributes, may be 100),  so i cannot access them through person.name and person.phone, etc. Is there anyway to cycle through the attributes of the object?

Comment: I also added my updated code to the bottom of my post

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when you say you can't access them through their attribute name?  are you suggesting that the properties will be different for each person?

Comment: so for my set of data, id o not know if each person (object) will have 2 attributes (name, phone) or if they will have an infinite number of attributes.  so i need to be able to create a row for each attribute that may appear, in a loop opposed to manually.

Comment: Your data isn't structured in a way that makes that possible.

Comment: would you be able to recommend some sort of data structure that could be used?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a method to do what you are asking and I'm struggling to come up with a good solution.  HTML table (and DataTable plugin rendering) runs left to right, top to bottom.  so you get an object per row, and a column per property.  You would have to invert this, where you would have an array of objects that each represents a row, and each of these objects would have to hold a single property from the real data object, and trying to represent unlimited properties would be difficult.